# Can anyone explain why my Carbon setup is not retaining data?

Tags: logging, collectd

I have a Carbon install which is being fed data from a load of hosts running Collectd - the data is only being kept for 24 hours even though I've configured my storage-schemas correctly.

storage-schemas.conf:

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[collectd]
pattern = ^collectd.*
retentions = 10s:2d,1m:14d,5m:1y

[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 60s:1d
```

Now should my collectd filter not grab any data coming in such as the following?

```
collectd.node_hostname_net.interface-br-vlan.if_packets.rx
```

If that works then surely my collectd retention should be applied and kept for longer than 24 hours? Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I solved my own issue - it was simply that when I initially configured Carbon I forgot to configure the storage-schema for collectd - I did this after I started receiving data. Whisper files set retention on data when they are created and thus my retention changes wouldn't affect my existing metrics.

To fix this I ran https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper#whisper-resizepy against each Whisper file with the required retention periods.